# Centering image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to present an image in the center of my canvas using the ctx.drawimage function.

The image failed to display after I defined its coordinates as (canvas.width - image.width)/2,(canvas.height - image.height)/2.

```
function drawFace(){
    var image = images[trialCounter];
    ctx.drawImage(image,
    (canvas.width - image.width)/2,
    (canvas.height - image.height)/2,
    220, 270
    );
}
```

Instead of displaying the image at the center of the screen, the image stopped showing up. I didn't have trouble when I simply had canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2 as the coordinates.

Comment: Where from did you get 220 and 270? Is image.width = 220 and image.height = 270?

Comment: yes, I set them to 220 & 270 because the image is actually much larger

Comment: In this case try  `ctx.drawImage(image,
    (canvas.width - 220)/2,
    (canvas.height - 270)/2,
    220, 270);`

Comment: I tried that and it worked! Thanks!